# How to load an image in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display an image in my shiny app but I can't find the path I have to give.

My app structure is the following :

```
App>
  server.R
  ui.R
  wwww>
    images>
      image.png
```

And I have the following code :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(img(src = "www/images/image.png"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

It doesn't work.

I tried a lot of syntax for the path, even something like

options("shiny.port" = 8080)
    img(src = paste0("http://127.0.0.1:", getOption("shiny.port"), "/www/images/image.png"))

But i'm realy struggling to disply the image, in the html inspector I always have "failed to load the given url".
If you have any ideas... thanks !

NB : I'm able to load css with the same syntax (i.e. tags$style("www/css/style.css"))

Comment: Too many "w"s in the directory name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should works without the "www/" prefix : `img(src = "images/image.png")`